# New Anthropology and Sociology Stack Exchange proposal

Tags: support, site-promotion, goals

We have recently created a new proposal on Area 51 that focuses on **Anthropology and Sociology**.

Anthropology and sociology are two closely related fields. Anthropology focuses on the scientific study of human behavior and cultures of both the present and past, including past human species, while sociology more focuses on the scientific study of social behavior and the patterns of social relationships and interaction in humans.

Creation of this site will help improve efficiency addressing common problems/questions, as well as being a good open resource for those wanting to learn more about anthropology and sociology.

***This site is different than Biology<sup>1</sup>/Medical Sciences.*** This site may include questions related to how cultural norms have risen within different societies. This site may include questions related to how social relationships and interaction affect the aspects of culture in our everyday life, or it may include questions related to analytical/mathematical approaches to sociological problems.

During the proposal we intend to define the scope of questions appropriate for the Anthropology and Sociology Stack Exchange site.

We invite anyone with an interest in anthropology or sociology to join our site and encourage you to submit example questions that you might hope that this site would answer, and vote on questions you would like to see answered on this site.

> How would ***YOU*** use this site?

[Join Anthropology and Sociology Stack Exchange Proposal on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/128260/anthropology-and-sociology)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Although while there is a bit of an overlap here with the [anthropology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anthropology) tag, if I'm (hopefully) not mistaken that is for questions that are more related to biological anthropology.</sup>